# Skyrim loading screen crash

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, technical-issues

I have been playing some modded Skyrim lately, and it worked perfectly fine; I played for about 1 hour straight without any problems.

When I went to Adriane in Whiterun (After newly purchasing upgrades for the Breezehome house (With a Breezehome mod)) then when I went into my inventory after asking her what she was selling (Where I sell stuff to her) it suddenly just crashed. I have been looking a little bit here and there, but ended up being tired and decided to just ask you amazing people. The mods I have activated are the following:

- Amazing Follower Tweaks
- Apachii Skyhair (With the bonus female hair pack)
- Bijin Wives
- Breezehome FullyUpgradeable (Dawnguard and Heartfire compatible)
- Calientes Beautiful Bodies Edition (CBBE)
- Cloaks Of Skyrim
- Demon Hunter Armor V2 (CBBE Compatible)
- Fores New Idles In Skyrim (Not using on any of the mods, just never bothered to deactivate)
- Frostfall
- Inigo
- Moonpath To Elsweyr (Including dialogue bug fix)
- Remodeled Armor
- ShowRaceMenu Prechache Killer (Required for Apachii Skyhair)
- Sky UI
- TERA Armor Collection
- UFO (Ultimate follower overhaul)
- Windcallers Pass
- Skyrim SKSE (Script extender) (Not sure if it counts as a mod)

If a log is needed please tell me, and how to get a hold of it.

Comment: The first thing I would try to do is uninstall Breezehome Fully Up-gradable since that is the mod that would most likely cause the crash since you were in Breezehome when you crashed.

Comment: Also, your title is misleading. If you crashed in Breezehome, don't title your question "Loading Screen Crash".

Comment: I didn't crash in Breezehome, I crashed by Adriane's forge about 5 minutes after I purchased upgrades for Breezehome. But I crash in the loading screen after the first crash.

Comment: Also remembered I added a bat file to instantly make all skills lv 100 with all perks, have yet to use it though

Comment: I tried to disable it, but the crash still occurs.

Comment: There could be an item issue with TERA armor collection that is messing with Adriane's inventory. The only way to know for sure what is crashing your game is to disable every mod you have and add them back 1 by 1. This is one of the reasons I did not heavily mod my Skyrim, because of these issues. It got too frustrating after a while.

Comment: Currently testing to disable the Tera armors mod, but when I tried to load an old save it crashed as well, although it was about half a second AFTER the loadingscreen. So it seems unlikely that it's the Tera mod.

Comment: Disabling the Tera armor mod did not work.

Comment: Thank you ChaseC, you gave me the motivation to do the boring part which was to do what you told me to do (The activate 1 by 1 part) And the sinner was Frostfall.

Comment: You're welcome! That'll be $9.99 :)

Comment: Trying to figure out exactly which mod isn't very helpful to the internet at large. Asking us to pinpoint which it is among a dozen or more mods is too broad.

Comment: More like asking in case someone happened to have an incompatibility issue amongst the following mods. If you cant answer the question, just ignore it. There are no stupid questions, and no answer is just one version of a non-stupid answer. This question was written 3 years ago though, no need to necropost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, the Frostfall mod was the sinner somehow. Thanks guys ^-^

Comment: Can't do it till tomorrow :v

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is check the ratings on the mod you downloaded, and see what the problem may be. Once done you should try taking that mod off and turn off your console and try again.

Comment: I am trying to disable every mod and enable them 1 by 1, but while they are disabling I will try what you just said :d Thanks for your reply

Comment: Glad I could help….